# Преобразование из DOS (cp866) в windows(cp1252)

Tags: c#, кодировка, dos

```
string text = "€¢â®¯ àª";
Encoding cp1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding cp866 = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
byte[] cp866Bytes = cp866.GetBytes(text);
byte[] cp1252Bytes = Encoding.Convert(cp866, cp1252,cp866Bytes);
string newStr = cp1252.GetString(cp1252Bytes);
```

на выходе получаю "??aR? a?".
Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: А что должно быть на выходе?

Comment: ... и почему вы ожидаете, что на выходе будет что-то другое?

Comment: Ошибки нет. Символа евро и цента в кодировке cp866 нет, например. Вы видимо задачу неправильно поняли. Видимо в исходном состоянии есть набор байтов, который отображается, как "€¢â®¯ àª" в кодировке 1252 и задача отобразить истинный текст. Для этого вам нужно наоборот: получить набор байтов в 1252 и после получить из этих байтов текст. Например так: 'string newStr = cp866.GetString(cp1252.GetBytes(text));'. Должно же получится "Автоп рк"?

Comment: Спасибо все верно подсказали.